# And operator causing problem for null value

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am having a stored procedure that has a searching logic based on different filters. Now, SP is using those filters to return the data. Some of those filters are enabled from the Admin panel hence in the case of disabled filters, null values are being passed.

One of the disabled filters is creating a problem so I am just trying to wrap it inside the "IF block" but having a problem doing so.

That disabled filter is "`JobTypes`" where the user can search based on JobTypes whether its `"A", "B", "C" or "D" and so on the level job`. For now, it's disabled.

**Code:**

```
ALTER  PROC [dbo].[SearchJobs]
(
@companyId   INT, 
@jobTypeId   INT, 
--other params
AS
    BEGIN
     DECLARE @_jobTypeId INT;
     SET @_jobTypeId = @jobTypeId;
    --other logic
      CREATE TABLE #tempJobTypes
        (JobTypeId INT
        );
        IF @_jobTypeId = 1
            INSERT INTO tempJobTypes
            VALUES(1);
            ELSE
            IF @_jobTypeId = 2
                INSERT INTO #tempJobTypes(JobTypeId)
            VALUES(1), (2);
        ..like wise all other pre define conditions for job types
select * from Jobs
where title=@searchTerm
AND (JobTypeId IN
                (
                    SELECT *
                    FROM #tempJobTypes
                ))
```

So now, since we have this `JobTypes` disabled, so I want to execute it inside SP only if `its not null and have value > 0` but problem is this condition :

```
AND (JobTypeId IN
                (
                    SELECT *
                    FROM #tempJobTypes
                ))
```

How do I build it dynamically?

Comment: Can you include all the relevant code, seem to be missing bits eg no declaration of @_jobTypeId, missing params. A clear example with sample data and desired output will help us help you,  [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Stu Updated my question to declare the jobTypeId. Actually, it's a huge SP hence I have just included the relevant portion. I hope it helps and sorry for missing the parts

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
AND (JobTypeId IN (SELECT * FROM #tempJobTypes) OR
     NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #tempJobTypes)
    )
```

This ignores `JobTypeId` if there are no rows in the temporary table.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I'll admit this is rather confusing but it looks like you're just building a list of integers in a temp table between 1 and the value of `@jobTypeId`. So if `@jobTypeId` was 7 you'd end up with a temp table with 7 rows values 1-7?

Your criteria then is surely just...

```
and jobTypeId between 1 and @jobTypeId and @jobTypeId is not null
```